log4net latency (delay in IO operations)
I am using RollingFileAppender of the log4net package to write logs.
It appears that log4net writes log messages in batches, so sometimes there's like 10-15 seconds delay before message appear in the log file, which I completely understand, as an IO optimization.
However, I have a specific use case, that I would like to have no more than 1 second delay. Is it possible to configure log4net to close file after each log line (or in frequency of 1 second) ?
I went though documentation, and can't see such option. Or perhaps there is some pattern I can follow, some force close that I can add to the code code ?

Does this answer your question? Log4Net RollingFileAppender not flushing IO buffer with low volume log

If your requirement is to write directly be aware that its not completely in the hands of log4net but also dependent in the setup of your Filesystem/OS. If your OS or the Controller for the drive does write caching you need to look at that also.
